# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "string memory"

Tags: solidity

I want to convert `uint price` to `string`.
I used

```
string(price);
```

but did't work

Answer (score 4):

you can use **openzeppelin** library

add this to top of your file

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
```

then use it like this

```
Strings.toString(price);
```

read more in [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/utils#Strings)